# Validation loss is zero on first epoch only

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning, tensorflow-datasets, tf.keras

### Problem

I am trying to build a regression model in tensorflow using the dataset and keras API's. The target contains quite a lot of zero's and the non-zero values are roughly distributed normally though all are positive.

When I try to create the linear model below I notice that on the first epoch the validation loss and both of the validation metrics are exactly 0, though the training loss and metrics are not. This problem disappears after the first epoch. Though this doesn't keep me from creating the model I still can not explain why this happens and what I might do about it.

### Tried so far

What I have unsuccesfully tried to pinpoint where the problem lies:

- Swapping `train` and `test`
- A smaller batchsize (32 instead of 255)
- Shuffling `test`
- Setting the initalizers of the dense layer to normal

### My code

```py
train = tf.data.experimental.make_csv_dataset(...)
test = tf.data.experimental.make_csv_dataset(...) # a smaller csv file

model = Sequential([
    DenseFeatures(features),
    Dense(1, activation='linear') # we are doing a regression
])
model.compile(
    optimizer='adam',
    loss='mean_squared_error',
    metrics=['mean_squared_error', 'mean_absolute_error']
)
model.fit(train,
          epochs=2, 
          validation_data=test
)
```

Comment: Seems to be a reporting (as opposed to calculation) problem - when I add callbacks, my `on_epoch_end` gets a non-zero loss:

Answer (score 1):

This is completely normal because normal metrics and validation metrics are computed in different times.

Nomral metrics are computed **during the epoch**, so you can see what is the loss score and other values that come from the training.

Validation metrics are used to see wether the parameters computed during a certain epoch are good. This means that some of the training data used in a specific epoch (you can specify the percentage) are not used for training, but they're used intead to compute the network accuracy. So theese values are computed **at the end of the epoch**, when you have a certain parameter configuration.

Comment: I'm not sure why it makes sense that the validation loss is exactly 0.0 at the end of the epoch.

Comment: Because validation is a step after training. The pipeline is like this: you train the network, but you don't know if it's any good, THEN you make validation on data that the net has never seen. During this step validation loss is computed, so only after the training epoch.

Comment: I understand how a validation loss is computed but not why it is consistently 0.0 instead of some finite positive value. Could this be a bug?

Comment: Is the problem only during the first epoch? I don't understand

Comment: The problem indeed only occurs on the first epoch.

Comment: @M.Ungheretti Did you happen to find out why this error occurs? Similar thing is happening for me. (Seems like loss explodes for that epoch)

Comment: Unfortunately I did not. Since this issue does not impact the final performance I decided to leave it.